# Checkbox takes two clicks to check every time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am currently running a react app that has a checkbox that looks like this:

`<input name="~" classsName="~" type="checkbox" onChange={this.onToggle}/>`

The `onToggle` function looks like this:

```
onToggle = (e) => {
    const { value } = suppressEvent(e).target;
    const newState = {...this.state, checkboxOn:value}
    this.setState(({ newState }) => ({ newState: !newState}));
}
```

The issue is that on the web page, the checkbox only switches its condition after two clicks every time. Any ideas on how I can make it switch after one click? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your variable naming and use of the function argument just makes this so confusing. You set `newState` to an object, but then treat it like it's a boolean. Are you simply trying to invert the boolean value of `this.state.checkboxOn` in this function?

Comment: Hi. I was wondering if this checkbox has a `checked` attribute as well. I presume it is checked if `this.state.checkboxOn` is true, but I just want to make sure since it's not in the snippet?

Comment: @Jayce444 Sorry about making it so confusing. I was trying to simplify things for the question. Yes I am using the boolean value to put a request in to the backend. But that's not the issue, the checkbox is.

Comment: @stefan It does not have a checked attribute. Will that help the problem with the checkbox needing two clicks?

Comment: @jhf2 I believe so. You handle the events from that checkbox but how do you determine if it should be checked or not? That should come from the state of your component/ application. Try  adding `checked={this.state.checkboxOn}` You can find an example in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue try rewriting your component like this:

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true
    };
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
  }

  onToggle() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { checked: !prevState.checked };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input name="~" className="~" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.onToggle} />
          <label htmlFor="~">Checkbox</label>
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify({ state: this.state }, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Checkbox />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App { font-family: sans-serif; }
pre { background: #efefef; padding: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Still taking two clicks to check the checkbox. Thanks for your extremely well written and thorough answer though!